# TimeZone broken in SimpleDateFormat in android 2.3

Tags: java, android, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

Android 2.3 was recently released last night. So naturally I tried my app on it and found there was date formatting issue.  I have noticed the DateFormatter produces different formats. So do this in a simple Java program:

```
((SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, 
    DateFormat.LONG)).format(new Date());
```

Output is

> December 7, 2010 11:49:40 AM EST

Do the same thing in an android emulator and you get

> December 7, 2010 11:42:50 AM GMT-05:00

Notice the different time zone. Has anybody ran in to this issue? Is there another formatter I can use that doesn't depend on Java's implementation?

**EDIT:**
Ok so here is more detail to why I think this is broken:

Using this code:

```
private final DateFormat format = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
```

I tried to parse a date but the following error is thrown:

```
12-07 12:55:49.556: ERROR/DateDeserializer(847): Error when parsing date
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon, 06 Dec 2010 17:13:35 EST"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
    at com.currency.mobile.client.DateDeserializer
        .deserialize(DateDeserializer.java:31)
    at com.currency.mobile.client.DateDeserializer
        .deserialize(DateDeserializer.java:19)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty
        .deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:149)
```

Comment: ps, if I remove EST and z then everything works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the output.
You create a [DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28int,%20int%29)-Instance which depends on the default [Locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). It is not unusual that on different machines, different java-installations the default Locale vary and so the output of locale-dependent operations. In this case the default [TimeZone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) is different, but the two outputs in your question represent the same Date, printed with the same format String `MMMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z`.

**UPDATE:**
parse() in Android 2.3 will work with TimeZones like `GMT+xxxx` etc, but it doesn't recognize `EST` for example as a valid TimeZone for parsing. Android knows about `EST` if you use `TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")`.

**UPDATE2:**

[Three-letter timezone IDs "EST", "HST", and "MST" are deprecated.](http://crmondemand.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/dst-faq-138158.html#threeletter) Do not use them.

Comment: I added more detail to why I think this is broken.

Comment: if u use the 'z' but with GMT-00:05 it works ? maybe google removed the text presentation and use only numeric form ?

Comment: No, if remove 'z' and EST then it works. Currently, I have a hacked solution to fix this but this didn't happen in 2.3. I tried using Locale.US too and still no luck

Comment: I didnt see your update until now. But yea I figured it doesn't work in 2.3 and have used the TimeZone solution my self. I will still accept your answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

Both are same TimeZone just different representation

Comment: Yes I noticed that. Except DateFormat.parse() is broken now. Because it doesn't support that pattern

Comment: @Amir: Why do you think `parse()` cannot handle this?

Comment: I'll add more detail in a second

Answer (score 1):

Looks like support for pattern "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" is also broken.

Evgueni

Comment: I have: 12-31 16:23:20.874: WARN/System.err(548): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Dec 20 22:15:23 UTC 2010"
12-31 16:23:20.884: WARN/System.err(548):     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)