# Why does this SimpleDataFormat parsing fail on Android?

Tags: java, android, parsing, simpledateformat

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");

sdf.parse("Sun Dec 13 10:00:00 UTC 2009")
```

result

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Sun Dec 13 10:00:00 UTC
>   2009

Note: This code seems to work in a normal Java application but seems to fail on Android.

Comment: btw, i always find these kind of question quite unworthy for a SO, is it better to remove these kind type of questions after i've found a solution?

Comment: There is a duplicate exist for this I know , Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668696/parsing-from-string-to-date)

Comment: what is your Java version and locale? to me, `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse("Sun Dec 13 10:00:00 UTC 2009")` outputs date without exception

Comment: just for testing, doing the inverse can be useful: `System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()))`

Comment: Anyone tried this on Android? I've found out it only occurs on Android...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger good suggestion, it return "Tue Nov 8 11:49:08 GMT+01:00 2011", i'm just wondering if the implementation of DataFormat differs on Android, it shouldn't in my opinion as it lives in the same package...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't for me - perhaps your default locale uses different month names? Specify the locale for the format.

```
// Will definitely work
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                      Locale.US);

// Will definitely not work
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                      Locale.FRANCE);

// Might work - depends on default locale
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy")
```

(The problem is the names of the days of the week and months of the year, which are obviously culture-specific. Date and time separators can vary too.)

EDIT: It's odd that you're still having problems. Just to check, please try to run the following short but complete program:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {        
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                              Locale.US);
        sdf.parse("Sun Dec 13 10:00:00 UTC 2009");
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, try taking out the time zone part of both the pattern and the text. I wonder whether it's having problems with that.

EDIT: If the Android `SimpleDateFormat` implementation doesn't manage to parse the time zone, you can probably just use:

```
text = text.replace(" UTC ", " ");
Date parsed = sdf.parse(text);
```

... having set the time zone on the parser to UTC, of course. You probably want to check that it *contains* " UTC " first, just in case your data format changes.

Comment: aha right, good idea! ;) it data retrieved from a remote server, so maybe different locale...

Comment: really strange but it doesn't work for me, not for Locale.US or Locale.ENGLISH...

Comment: Locale.getDefault() returns 'en_NL'

Comment: That will explain. Note that NL cab be particularly tricky for months, as it will can work with English months for about half a year until it runs into a month that does not work.

Comment: @SanderVersluys, what do you get if you parse using the US locale and format using the default Locale.  Unless you get the same thing, I suspect you will have a problem, because the Day and Month is in English.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well well, a test app like you provided does idd works i've also found out... BUT running the same code in an Android project does not! Any ideas? (i'll change tags)

Comment: @Thirler yes, that's idd correct, i'm providing the Locale now like it should but it seems like it still doesn't parse on Android... so there has to be a difference in the DateFormat implementation...

Comment: @SanderVersluys: Yes, that's entirely possible - have you tried removing the "UTC" part to see whether that's what's tripping it up?

Comment: I'm not the only one it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379261/timezone-broken-in-simpledateformat-in-android-2-3#4572781

Comment: Stripping out the UTC timezone part does idd seem to fix it, darn... this will make some messy code for parsing... Thank you @JonSkeet

Comment: @SanderVersluys: Will the time zone *always* be UTC?

Comment: @JonSkeet if you update your answer with the 'strip UTC part' suggestion for Android, it will be truly the right anwser... ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes normally it will, but idd, it makes more dangerous to break the Android client in the future because of that assumption...

Answer (score 3):

Your format looks correct. Is it possible that you are not using an English Locale though? The formatter will take your system locale  and this could result in different names for 'sun' and 'dec'